# jQuery when input is intervals of X, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, intervals

I have an input which will have a certain number in it.  If they put an incorrect interval number in the input and click the submit button I want it to alert instead of proceeding.

Best shown in Example:

Say one enters 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11.  I would want an `alert("Please enter intervals of 6")` show up and the addtocart input not fired.  The input value on each page is dynamic, and could be 1, 6, 12, etc..

```
<input value="6" type="text" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" >    
<input class="vCSS_input_addtocart" type="image" src="btn_addtocart.gif" name="btnaddtocart" onclick="return addToCart(this.form, this);">
```

Perhaps I have to use a `change()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Modulus function like:

```
<input class="txt" value="6" type="text" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" /> 


  if (!(($(".txt").val() % 6 == 0) || ($(".txt").val()==1)))
  {
   alert("Not interval of 6 or value of 1");   
  }
```

Operators/Modulus.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040_Operators/Modulus.htm

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3SEJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value<0 || (value!=1 && value%6!=0)) {
   alert("I'm sorry, I can't let you buy that.");
}
```

Comment: good catch of `1` being ok. Your message will fail if they input `-12`.

Comment: so close, but what happens when they enter 0?

Comment: Depends on the context. If they're ordering eggs, zero is a perfectly acceptable value. If zero isn't valid, just change `value<0` to `value<=0`.